# vecorization of fzero() iterative solution in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, iteration, vectorization

I have a family of problems that requires search for 2 optimal/root values. As a mere example let's say:

F+(F*G)/3=1  and G+(F*G)/4=19/16

(Of course this is really simple to solve with algebra) The actual problem is way too complicated to write here, but this simplifies the idea of what i intend to achieve.

The way I require to solve the problem is using fzero() function of matlab this is my code this far but is not working

```
x = fzero(@(F) [1;19/16]-F-myfun(F),[0;0]);
```

where myfun() is defined as

```
function [FF]=myfun(F)

FFx=(F(1,1)*F(2,1))/3;  
FFy=(F(2,1)*F(1,1))/4;  

FF=[FFx;FFy];
end
```

and F is an array with two elements (F=[fx;fy]). A 1D version of this is no problem. However when I upscale to 2D the following error appears

```
Attempted to access F(2,1); index out of bounds because numel(F)=1.
```

As I understand from this, fzero() automatically makes F a 1x1 variable.  What do I need to do in order to make fzero assume F as a 2x1 array?

Comment: The first line from `help fzero` says "`fzero  Single-variable nonlinear zero finding.`" That means it only works in 1D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `fzero` is not for **systems** of equations.

Use `fsolve` instead.

Plus, all the code could be simplified and be written into only 2 lines like below:

`myfun=@(F) [1;19/16]-F-[ (F(1)*F(2))/3 ; (F(1)*F(2))/4];
x = fsolve(@(F) myfun(F),[1;1]);`

Comment: Thanks this really helped me to implement the solution in the actual problem

Comment: @JaredLo Glad I could help.